# Generate Bootchart report for application in external hardware connected to android studio in windowspc

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio

I made an application in android studio using java, I am using windows machine, I want to generate bootchart report,  i have an external device connected to the pc, can anybody help me, In windows or in Linux, how do i generate a bootchart report

I tried to find on internet but couldn't, tried on chat gpt as well but the commands it told showed errors

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.